# I'd like to discern if the Infinitive complement is nominal or adjectival as in "I want you to go there."

Tags: grammar, object-complements

Would you tell me If the infinitive complement is nominal or adjectival as in

> **I want you to go there**

I thought "*you to go there*" is the object of the verb "*want*". i.e., the infinitive complement is nominal.

> I (S) + want (V) + you to go there (O)

But, my googling, [role of infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84638/role-of-infinitive) tells me *...The catenative complement is "to go there", not "you to go there", for the latter is not a constituent, but a sequence of direct object + complement.*

If so, is it grammatically correct for me to get that the infinitive complement, "*to go there*" is adjectival, post-modifying "*you*"?

> I (S) + want (V) + you (O) + to go there (Objective Complement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the traditional view, or at least very close to it.

> They named him Jeffrey.

Here, the arguments of the verb "named" are the direct object "him" and the object complement "Jeffry".   These two arguments are separate references to the same referent.   That is to say, "him" and "Jeffrey" are the same person.

This is what predicate nominative object complements do.  They restate their objects.

> Birthday parties always make him happy.

Here, the arguments of the verb "make" are the direct object "him" and the object complement "happy".   The adjective "happy" doesn't behave like a noun.   It doesn't have a referent.   That is to say, "him" and "happy" aren't the same person.

This is what predicate adjectival object complements do.  They modify their objects.

> I want you to go there.

The infinitive phrase "to go there" can be a referent and can do the same kinds of jobs that nouns typically do.   Like the object complements of my first two examples, it is the second argument of its governing verb.

However, "you" and "to go there" aren't the same person.   In fact, "to go there" isn't a person at all.   It's not another reference to the same referent.

Since the infinitive isn't doing what predicate nominative object complements do, it must be doing what predicate adjectival object complements do.   The phrase "to go there" modifies "you".

Labeling it as *postmodifying* may be going one step too far.   It would be a good label if the words "you to go there" were a coherent phrase and a single constituent.   Instead, we have two separate constituents, each acting as an individual argument of the governing verb.

Comment: Could you tell me If "from smoking" is also an adjectival complement modifying "him" as in "I prevented him from smoking"? or is it an adverbial complement modifying "prevented"?

Comment: If "prevented" licensed an object complement, we should be able to use nouns and adjectives as that argument.  Since we can't, that prepositional phrase must have an adverbial role.  However, the otherwise similar "I kept him from smoking" might have an object complement.  Sentences like "I kept him happy" certainly have predicate adjective arguments.